# Apache CXF And javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, response

i have a methode deleteProduct:

```
        @Override
        public Response deleteProduct(String productId) {
            Response response = Response
                    .status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
                    .entity(new IllegalAccessError("This is a JAXB object with an error string"))
                    .build();
            return response;
        }
```

my problem is always i get this response :

```
      <ns2:deleteProductResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.cxf.test.com/">
         <return/>
      </ns2:deleteProductResponse>
```

why i dont see my message error ?

Comment: would you please check the annotations properly http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html

Comment: annotation of what the response is a javax.ws.rs.core.Response object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused between `JAX-RS` and `JAX-WS` . If this is `SOAP-UI` you are referring to, it means you are building SOAP based web services or, in other words are using `SOA` - service oriented architecture which works on the SOAP protocol and not HTTP. Hence HTTP Status codes or error messages based on them do not come into picture here.

However, if you are building a RESTful web service (one that is based on `JAX-RS`), it has everything to do with HTTP.

First, decide what framework to use based on your project requirements and then code accordingly.